# CURL/PHP Is there a way for visitor to download remote file?

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way for my visitor to download a file which is in another site that is behind a login ?

**The problem :**
- The filename list is on another site behind a login
- You have to login to download

currently my code can login with curl and display the link to download file , user can click the link but they can't download because their browser is not logged in to that site.

I know i can save the file temporary with curl ( download the file with curl to my server and the visitor download from my server )

But Is there a way to allow them to download directly from my site ?

I hope i explain the problem clearly.
ps. its my university site, and its painful to check if there is a new things to download, so i want to make it easier for my friends.

Thanks

Comment: You have the script that does the download already. You have your friends using your site. All ingredients are there. So, if your friend clicks a link to your site, your site downloads the file via curl from uni site and sends that response back to your friend - that means job done. So yes, there is a way. You're creating an API that consumes another API. You have everything. What exactly confuses you? The curl response you get back - you can immediately send it somewhere else (it's called proxying).

Comment: @Mjh No , it does not do the download. currently my code only display a list of things available to download and user can click on them. but when they click them they get an alert that they are not logged in. ( the alert is from my uni site )

Comment: If you managed to log in to uni website, then you can download from uni website. cURL the list of files, show it to your buddies, let them pick the file, pass the URI back to your site, use your code to auth + download the file, send the response back to your friends. Downloading a file, fetching a page, logging in - it's the same mechanism for HTTP.

Comment: How do the visitor can get the file ? i can display the download link , but when you click the link , you can't download it because you ( your browser are not logged in ).

Comment: Pass that link back to your site. Don't redirect user there.. then have your site download the file and send it back.

Answer (score -2):

I think , you have to use this url on the link .

```
$username = 'abc';
$pasword = 'xyz';
$file_url = "google.com";
http://$usename:$password@$file_url
```